# Can I remove all non-zsh related shell files on Catalina since bash is being deprecated in favor of zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh, macos

macOS will be using zsh moving forward and we can set zsh as the default shell in Catalina which I have done. With Catalina is it ok if I remove all traces of bash and oh-my-zsh since zsh is now the default shell? Also I am using Hyper Terminal which means I do not need oh-my-zsh any longer right.

**Example:**
The Anaconda installer added this script originally to my bashrc or bash_profile so I copied it over to .zshrc when I switched to zsh. I recently read I didn't need to/shouldn't have copied it over since it was meant for the bash_profile but now that macOS is moving to use zsh anyway I'd like to know what I should do. Obviously I need to tell zsh where Anaconda is but do I need that script or can I just export the Anaconda path like `export PATH=/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin:$PATH`?

Can I just leave this Anaconda script in zshrc and remove all traces of bash to future-proof my Mac when bash is gone?

```
export PATH=/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin:$PATH

# added by Anaconda3 2019.03 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/ty604/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/ty604/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

I also have many duplicate paths in $PATH because of duplicate export commands in various shell files. 
**$ echo $PATH**
`/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin:/Users/ty604/anaconda3/condabin:/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin:/Users/ty604/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Users/ty604/flutter/bin`

Files in my system
`.bash_history, .bash_profile, .bashrc, .profile, .zprofile, .zsh_history, .zshrc, .zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh`

Folders in my system
`.bash_sessions, .oh-my-zsh, .zsh`

Comment: As far as I know, `bash` is not going away on macOS. It's just that `zsh` (which has been part of macOS for some time) is now the _defualt_ login shell. You should not try to "delete `bash`" from your system, as that may well break stuff (`/bin/sh` is still `bash`, for example).

Comment: Yes it is going away because of licensing. That's why zsh has become default.

Comment: There is nothing `bash`-specific in that Coda setup code. Are you having issues with it under `zsh`?

Comment: I also don't see any duplicated entries in your `$PATH`.  What is your question?

Comment: If you take a look, there are two instances of `/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin`. I am assuming that is because `export PATH=/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` is in more than one shell file such as `.zshrc` and `.bashrc`. And actually I found it in `.bash_profile` as well. Since `zsh` is my default shell and Catalina defaults to zsh can I remove that export  from `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`? And can I remove any `bash` and `oh-my-zsh` files since my default is now `zsh + Hyper`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell initialisation code that you show does not look `bash`-specific and should work with `zsh` as well, assuming that the various script that it sources are working too (`shell.bash` and `conda.sh`). If there is a `shell.zsh` script you could obviously choose to use that instead of `shell.bash`.

---

In the `zsh` shell, the `PATH` variable is tied to the `path` array.  You can make both contain only unique entries using `typeset -U`.

This is an example using your particular value of for `PATH`:

```
$ print -rC1 -- $path
/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin
/Users/ty604/anaconda3/condabin
/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin
/Users/ty604/.cargo/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public
/usr/local/share/dotnet
/Users/ty604/flutter/bin
```

The path `/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin` is duplicated at the start.  To make the paths unique (now and in the future):

```
$ typeset -U PATH path
$ print -rC1 $path
/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin
/Users/ty604/anaconda3/condabin
/Users/ty604/.cargo/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public
/usr/local/share/dotnet
/Users/ty604/flutter/bin
```

See also what happens if I push `/bin` onto the start of the path:

```
$ path=( /bin $path )
$ print -rC1 -- $path
/bin
/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin
/Users/ty604/anaconda3/condabin
/Users/ty604/.cargo/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public
/usr/local/share/dotnet
/Users/ty604/flutter/bin
```

(The second `/bin` is deleted.)

Since the `path` array is tied to the `PATH` variable, the changes will be visible there too:

```
$ print -rC1 -- $PATH
/bin:/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin:/Users/ty604/anaconda3/condabin:/Users/ty604/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Users/ty604/flutter/bin
```

Comment: ok those are handy commands. Thanks! But since `zsh` is now default on >macOS 10.15 can I remove all bash related files such as `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.bash_history` etc? And what `zsh` files are absolutely necessary? Only `.zshrc` or `.zprofile` as well?

Comment: @tem I would move them away rather than removing them, just until such time that you've noticed that nothing seems broken. `zsh` does not use the `bash` init files.  Only `.zshrc` is _necessary_ (the shell will print out a short message if it's not present) but it could be empty. Just like with `bash`, you have different init files for login shells and for interactive shells. `.zprofile` is similar to `.bash_profile` and `.zshrc` is similar to `.bashrc`.  This is covered in the manual under "STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES".

Comment: Yes I realize that `.zprofile` / `.bash_profile` and `.zshrc` / `.bashrc` are similar. I don't use `.bash_profile` so I was thinking I don't need `.zprofile` either. Yes, I mean move and save the files rather than delete. As long as it's safe to move them and test than I will move them. Lastly, what about that Anaconda script? It refers to `shell.bash`. Maybe I can change that line to `shell.zsh` and then move all `bash` files? Or just comment out the script and only use `export PATH=/Users/ty604/anaconda3/bin:$PATH`?

Comment: @tem If there _is_ a `shell.zsh`, you should use that. Otherwise either try the `shell.bash` script or inspect what it does and do similarly manually. If setting the `PATH` like you show is all that it does, then by all means do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have since found out that zsh does have a [hook](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8492#issuecomment-540611868) which means I can remove all instances of bash shell since the system $PATH is being sourced from `etc/profile` anyway.

macOS default shell is now zsh so for me, there is no use for bash files.